# Fill number used as shape with text

Tags: vector, inkscape, text, fill, word-cloud

After a long research process I couldn't find a way to write a text into a number. Writing them all one by one takes too long and any other way used to fill shapes with texts didn't work.

I would be grateful if someone could guide me using Inkscape. -  Or Gimp maybe.
I'm trying to fill in 17 with student names.

[image]

Comment: How shall it look like? There are multiple options thinkable.

Answer (score 1):

First you should convert the number into a path. Then, you should be able to get your whole text to flow into the shape as [described in the manual](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Text-Flow.html):

> To create a linked flowed text object, select a text object and one or more shape/path objects. Then use the Text → Flow into Frame (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) command.

If you tried that already, what exactly is not working?

Comment: Hi @juancho tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: 1. I add 1 then I convert it to a path using "Object to Path". 2. I choose my text then "1" I converted and when I press Flow into Frame nothing happens. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Juancho answer seems reasonable. Can you attach your SVG file to your question?